# matching a word (case insensitive) to a list and replace it to the word in the list - C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

lets say my string is `"this is a string"` 
my list is `{"tHis", "WoRd, "a", "iS"}`
and my regex patern is `{"tHis" | "WoRd" | "a" | "iS"}` 
The desired result is `"tHis iS a string"` 
the only idea i have is looping over the entire list and test it one by one against a substring

Comment: Are they words with no spaces inside? Only letters?

Comment: Basically you can't do without comparing each word to your list... you can only turn your list into a better searchable data structure, like a prefix tree or a hash table so you are faster at retrieving the replacement for an input word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
var dict = words.ToDictionary(x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b.+?\b", x =>
{
    string replace;
    dict.TryGetValue(x.Value, out replace);
    return replace ?? x.Value;
});
```

Note that the regex pattern is suboptimal, and will work only if the words are composed only by letters and digits. The `dict` can be reused (so you should cache it). I'm using the *like ... a hash table so you are faster at retrieving the replacement for an input word* suggestion by @grek40.

Comment: my pattern composed of letters numbers and symbols like '-', '. and '~'

Answer (score 0):

```
    string input = "this is a string";
    List<string> words = new List<string>(new[] { "tHis", "WoRd", "a", "iS" });
    string pattern = "\\b(" + string.Join("|", words) + ")\\b";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string output = reg.Replace(input, x => words.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Equals(x.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
```